# iOS: NSClassFromString return nil for a inner Class

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, class

If I write like this in **B.h** file:

```
@interface A : NSObject

@end

@interface B : NSObject

@end
```

Then NSClassFromString(@"A") will return nil.

However If I separate Class A from **B.h** like this:

in **A.h**

```
@interface A : NSObject

@end
```

in **B.h**

```
@interface B : NSObject

@end
```

Then NSClassFromString(@"A") will return non-nil

Why is Class A not loaded when in **B.h** ?

Comment: where you call `NSClassFromString` I think is related to visibility scope

Answer (score 2):

I just found that I forgot to write the implement of Class A.

So it's clear that if a class is just declared and not implemented, it will not be load in runtime.

Comment: yes, declarations are just information to help compiling. It's the implementations that are actually compiled.